# И снова "Illegal break statement" от break

Tags: javascript, break

Собственно, в чем проблема?

```
let j = 1;
let k = 0; // количество собранных мин
let roadMines = [true, false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true];

do{
    console.log(`Спасем рядового Райна!!! Погнали!!! 
        Перемещаемся на ${j} позицию`)
    if (roadMines[0] === true){
        k++;
        console.log(`1Вот подстава!! Мы наехал на мину. Мы сильно повреждены !!!`);
    } else {`Пронесло!!! На позиции ${j} нет мин. Едем дальше`}
    
} while(j < roadMines.length){
    console.log(`Перемещаемся на ${j+1} позицию`)
    if (roadMines[j] === true){
        k++;
        if (k === 2){
            console.log(`Шеф!!! Всё пропало!!! Мы снова наехал на мину. Мы не можем двигаться!!!`);
            break; <----- ОШИБКА ТУТ !!!
        } else {
            console.log(`2Вот подстава!!! Мы наехал на мину. Мы сильно повреждены !!!`);
        }; 
    } else {`Пронесло!!! На позиции ${j} нет мин. Едем дальше`};
    j++;
};
```

Comment: Собственно, что там, вне цикла, делает `break`?

Comment: И зачем Вы везде ставите `;` после закрывающих `}`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while

Comment: @Igor: _"... зачем Вы везде ставите `;`..."_ Если расставлять сразу и правильно, то не считаю это плохой практикой - таким способом хорошо выделяются окончания блоков условий (и не только) , при большой вложенности. Но, зато в других местах, ТС компенсировал :-)

Comment: @UModeL ...  после закрывающих `}`

Comment: нет цикла `do {...} while (...){...}` есть либо `do {...} while (...)` либо `while(...) {...}`

Comment: @Igor: я стараюсь ставить `;` в конце любой структуры (например, `if {...} ifelse {...} else {...};` или циклы, функции). Во всяком случае, делаю так на этапе отладки, а далее можно пройтись каким-нибудь клинером-бьютифиром.